# When is the closed subscheme of $\Bbb P^n_{\Bbb C}$ cut out by a homogeneous polynomial $f$ integral?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, affine-schemes, projective-schemes

I am new to algebraic geometry. I am trying to understand whether closed subschemes of $\mathbb P^n_{\mathbb C}$ is an integral scheme.

Let  $X = \operatorname{Proj} (A/(f))$ where $f$ is an homogeneous irreducible element of $A=\mathbb C[x_0,\ldots,x_n]$. I am trying to understand whether $X$ is an integral scheme.

It is clear to me that $X$ is a reduced scheme. It would be helpful, if someone can give me hints regarding irreducibility part.

Comment: Hint: Mimic the argument for the affine case. Other tips: `$\operatorname{Proj}$` is the way to format $\operatorname{Proj}$, and you don't need spaces on both sides of punctuation. I've made these formatting upgrades for you this time.